# How to make kurento support the use of G729 codec

Tags: gstreamer, kurento

I make a call, offer-answer is G729 codec. The call is using kurento as media server. When  kurento recorded its voice with webm file format. kurento printed error message.

2017-06-24 11:37:19,864920 2078 [0x00007fbe4fb698c0]   error KurentoMediaPipelineImpl  MediaPipelineImpl.cpp:42 busMessage()  Error on bus: error message: 0x7fbe34055630, time 99:99:99.999999999, seq-num 309, element 'udpsrc0', GstMessageError, gerror=(GError)NULL, debug=(string)"gstbasesrc.c(2948):\ gst_base_src_loop\ ():\ /GstPipeline:pipeline0/KmsRtpEndpoint:kmsrtpendpoint0/KmsRtpSessio n:kmsrtpsession0/GstUDPSrc:udpsrc0:\012streaming\ task\ paused\,\ reason\ not-linked\ (-1)";

Is gstreamer plugin not support G729 codec?

Answer (score 0):

The original kurento supports only opus、amr、raw. You can find some plugins based on gstreamer to support g729 , like : https://github.com/Kurento/gst-plugins-good/blob/master/gst/rtp/gstrtpg729depay.c .